# Change UserControl content in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have following UserControl defined in wpf:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Views.HideShowDetailsView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<DockPanel Background="#FFFFF2CC" Name="HideShowDetailsPanel">
    <Button Name="hidePatientDetails" 
            Background="Transparent" 
            Margin="10,10"
            Width="40"
            BorderBrush="Transparent"
            BorderThickness="0"
            DockPanel.Dock="Right"
            Command="{Binding Path=HideDetailsCommand}" >
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Image Source="../Resources/ArrowRight.png" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

And I need to change it's content by adding image canvas and another button when Command is activated. How this can be achieved in wpf?

Comment: you want to do it with or without changing the UC code?

Comment: I can change UC code if it is necessary.

Comment: you want do to do it in code behind?

Comment: Yes. From the code behind. I have found some code with bindings but can't do it right for my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by adding the two new controls to a container, say, `StackPanel` somewhere inside your UC. Then assign the following style to the `StackPanel`:

```
<Style x:Key="stackStyle" TargetType="StackPanel">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, ElementName=hidePatientDetails}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Will try. If this StackPanel is hidden in the beginning, does UC will be shrink and not include it in size measurement?

Comment: Yes, `Collapsed` shrinks control as it was not there. `Visibility=Hidden` hides it, but keeps the space for it.

Comment: Well that was the missing ingredient :) Thank you so much!